# Python read() raises MemoryError while readlines() works

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have a not so big text file (~220Mb), so it is much less than total amount of my RAM (12Gb) and even 2GB limit for 32bit process on my 64bit Windows7.

This simple code raises MemoryError and I do not understand why:

```
f_in = open (r"my_txt_file_220Mb.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf8')
txt = f_in.read ()
```

Strange, but just this code works:

```
txt = ''.join (f_in.readlines ())
```

I thought that it is the equivalent. What is the reason for MemoryError?

I am using 32 bit Python 3.4.2.

Comment: can you post the traceback? sounds strange indeed.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "1.10 read.py", line 2, in <module>`
`txt = f_in.read ()`
`MemoryError`
That's all.

Comment: In your second example try to do something with `txt` variable - at least print it's length. And then tell us if it fails with OOM or not.

Comment: you could try the first example with binary mode and without utf8 to see it if makes a diference: `f_in = open (r"my_txt_file_220Mb.txt", 'rb')`

Comment: It's ok with `print (len (txt))` - result is 226697651 symbols.

Comment: Hmm, binary mode works fine also with read(), no error. 243475940 bytes.

Comment: This is pure speculation, but.... if the file is read (200MB) and encoded into wchars (400MB) and the newlines are translated (another 400MB) thats half of available memory. Can you use an external profiler to see what happens to process memory before the explosion? Maybe reading chunks into a `TextIO` object would keep the numbers down. Of course you'd still have to get the text out of it...